# How can I run a groovy script from within a python script?

Tags: python, groovy

I got a groovy script that gives me an output file that I will use as an input file to a python script. I want to run the groovy script from within python instead of running groovy and then running python. If it is possible, please tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly 2 ways:

- Using the `os` library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os
os.system("groovy your_script.groovy")
```

- Using the `subprocess` library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["groovy", "your_script.groovy"])
```